# Does Jquery UI replace any functions from Jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, plugins

When I'm using Jquery UI, does it overwrite the old jquery default functions, like show and etc? Some of them have the same name but with different arguments, so I'm thinking maybe the old ones are overwritten.
And if this is really the case, what if I install some jquery plugins that use the functions that have been replaced? Will it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery UI doesn't overwrite any functions, it extends them so you can do more with them. Generally the regular jQuery core syntax will keep working when you include any jQuery UI functions.

Answer (score 1):

I think so. Because for example, when you use jQuery UI, you can `animate` background, too. Maybe it extends jQuery.